# javascript: is there a way too embed a blip.tv video via javascript?

Tags: javascript, mootools

Is it possible to embed a video via javascript like vimeo & moogaloop, but for blip.tv?

Their documentation seems unclear about how to do it, they have no example and I couldn't find any by googling for about 40 minutes..

Thanks, S.

Comment: They have an embed button on the videos.. do you want something different ?

Comment: I want to embed a video via javascript function. It has to be dynamically done

Comment: I didn't see a javascript-based embed code on Vimeo (only HTML <object> and iframe methods), can you post the dynamic embed code you came across for Vimeo as an example of what you need?

Comment: here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/5JCsd/, it's from their moogaloop documentation, (http://vimeo.com/api/docs/moogaloop, section "Example"­»"Moogaloop Javascript Example", that links to their github where I clicked on mootools.html)

Answer (score 1):

I finally came across a solution for what I wanted to do. If anybody is ever interested about it, here it is: (i'm using mootools)

```
function blipEmbed(episodeId) {
    var swf_id = 'embeddedPlayer';
    var moogaloop = new Swiff('http://blip.tv/scripts/flash/stratos.swf', {
        id : swf_id,
        container : 'playerHolder', /* the container's id where the swf will be embedded, i used a div */
        fullScreen: true,
        width : 1000,
        height : 500,
        vars : {
            file: "http://blip.tv/file/"+episodeId+"?skin=rss", 
            autostart: true, 
            allowm4v: true,
            showstrands: false,
            showguidebutton: false,
            showplaylist: false,
            showsharebutton: false,
            showmorebutton: false,
            showfsbutton: false,
            removebrandlink: true,
            showinfo: false,
            useoldendcap: false,
            enablejs: true
        }
    });

}

/* and for the callback, blip forces you to use this function*/

function getUpdate(changeType, param1, param2){
    if (changeType=="complete") {
        // when the video is done playing, do something
    }
}
```